# Face Swap and Face Detection/Recognition in Flutter

Tags: flutter, opencv, computer-vision, flutter-dependencies

How does one go about creating a Face Swap mechanism in Flutter?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: [Use this face swapping technique but convert it to flutter](https://pysource.com/2019/05/28/face-swapping-explained-in-8-steps-opencv-with-python/)

Comment: You could use Google ML kit (https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection) which is available in this package: https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit. When this is implemented you're able to detect faces in a live camerastream. From there taking images and swapping them would be my first try... Bit of hacking and prototyping will get you where you want.

Answer (score -2):

You’ll probably need a good plugin to do all the hard work for you. I recommend Google’s ML Kit on Flutter, as it is the most popular way to run on-device ML with Flutter.

The [face detection plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_face_detection) is what you want. You would basically get the face oval shape with [face contour detection](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection#example_2_face_contour_detection) and swap those shapes. And this can be done real-time with a given video input.

But you should keep in mind that the plugin is on v0.0.1. If you’re aiming for production, you’d better do that with Swift or Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how do we replace those Contour with another contour? How do we save the contour points as an Image. Any thoughts?

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple ways to archive this thing in Flutter. It might be in real-time or with some delay of seconds.

You can use one of these packages.

1. [Open CV](https://pub.dev/packages/opencv)
2. [TensorFlow](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite)
3. [Google's ML Kit](https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit)

It might be possible you will not get good support from openCV and TensorFlow in a flutter. But you can integrate the OpenCV/TensorFlow native libs or SDK for both Android and IOS and invoke them through [platform channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

There is also one more possible solution but it will definitely have a delay. For this kind of ML project python have great support of library and projects.

You can set up a python project which is responsible for face swapping it takes input from the flutter app (using rest API or socket) and return the output image after face-swapping.

Some great face swap projects are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/topics/face-swap) you can look into it.